# Best practices on python conditionals

Tags: python, if-statement, pep

When it comes to best practices on conditionals, which of the following examples is recommended?

```
def sum(arg1,arg2):
   if arg1>3:
     return
   else:
     return arg1+agr2
```

or

```
def sum(arg1,arg2):
   if arg1<3:
     return arg1+agr2
   else:
     return
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd use the second, but without the unnecessary `else` clause. If you don't have an explicit `return` statement, your function implicitly returns `None` when it reaches the end of the function.

Comment: `else` isn't necessary in the first one, either. If you don't return from the `if`, you'll just execute the next statement following the `if`, which can be `return arg1 + arg2`.

Comment: And finally, I'd consider whether it makes sense to raise an exception when `arg1 > 3`, rather than making the caller remember to check the return value for `None`.

Comment: Although, if you're following PEP8, `return` should be `return None`, and should be included: "If any return statement returns an expression, any return statements where no value is returned should explicitly state this as return None, and an explicit return statement should be present at the end of the function (if reachable):". So it depends on what style guide you're following.

Comment: Sidenote, [`sum()` is a builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), so to avoid [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) it, use a different name like `add` or `sum_`.

Comment: Also, note that the two examples aren't functionally identical. If `arg1 == 3`, the first will return `arg1+arg2` while the second will return `None`. (I'm assuming `agr2` is a typo.)

Comment: Thank you all for the enlightenment! The code was just an example, serving only for educational purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a ternary expression:

```py
def sum(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2 if arg1 < 3 else None
```

As an addendum, if one of the cases is unexpected or undesirable, I like to follow the [guard pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)), which involves checking for these cases first before performing your normal logic.

For example,

```py
def safe_divide(a, b):
    # Check preconditions at top of function definition
    if b == 0:
        return None

    # Checks passed, perform normal logic
    return a / b
```